# Verifying country and age

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my code to verify the age and country but keep coming back to this code as I cant get it to verify both. I'm new to JavaScript so don't understand to much.

```
function check(){
    var nbr;
    nbr = Number(document.getElementById("age").value);
    if(nbr < 18)
    {
       alert("Sorry you are not able to shop with us");
    }
    else
    {
       alert("Thank you, you may continue shopping");
    }
}

<form name="verify">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p style="margin-left: 90px;">Please confirm age and country</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="age">Age:</label><input id="age">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="Country">Country:</label>
      <select id="country" id="country" class="dropdown">
        <option value="select">--Select--</option>
        <option value="nz">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="aus">Australia</option>
        <option value="fiji">Fiji</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <li class="button">
    <button type="button" input type="button" onclick="check()">Submit</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I need to verify the drop down list so when the submit button is clicked with the correct age and country it has an alert that says you can continue shopping

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo inside your HTML file, `input type="button"` basically two times, so I've removed that.

In JS, I took the `.value` of your dropdown list (`<select>`), and I've put it inside `country` variable that I created as well.

Then, in `if` statement, we are asking if `nbr < 18`, *which was already there*, **OR** if the chosen option is `select` - `country === "select"`. If any of those two are true, user is not able to shop. Vice versa.

Hope that I explained this in the right way.

```js
function check(){
var nbr, country;
nbr = Number(document.getElementById("age").value);
country = document.getElementById("country").value;
if(nbr < 18 || country === "select")
{
   alert("Sorry you are not able to shop with us");
}
else
{
   alert("Thank you, you may continue shopping");
}
}
```

```html
<form name="verify">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p style="margin-left: 90px;">Please confirm age and country</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="age">Age:</label><input id="age">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="Country">Country:</label>
      <select id="country" class="dropdown">
        <option value="select">--Select--</option>
        <option value="nz">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="aus">Australia</option>
        <option value="fiji">Fiji</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <li class="button">
    <button type="button" onclick="check()">Submit</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```